# C++ Dynamic Array only getter works with overloaded [] operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants

I've got an overloaded [ ] operator in my C++ array. I have two of them:

```
ElType operator[](int position) const; //getter
ElType & operator[](int position); //setter
```

However, I've noticed that if I do for example:

```
std::cout << dynamicArray[4];
```

It only uses the setter, and basically just ignores the getter. Is there any way to make it use the getter? The problem is, my Getter has code to make sure that every time you assign a value, a variable called "size" is changed. But I don't want this to actually trigger when I'm only getting the value and not changing it.

The code for the getter is:

```
ElType DynArray::operator[](int position) const{
std::cout << "using getter" << std::endl;

return buffer_[position];
```

I've tried a lot of things at that point, like sticking a & into the getter, but that didn't work either. The getter is above the setter in the code too, if that matters.

Also, when constructing a dynamic array with capacity 5, is it a good practice to leave all the elements as they are (random values basically) or should I do a loop to set them all to null/zero?

Answer (score 0):

Since your getter is a `const` member function, you should be able to force the use of your getter by using a `const` object:

```
const DynArray cArray = dynamicArray;
std::cout << cArray[4];
```

Comment: Doesn't this mean I have to make a const object every time I want to use the getter since the setter wont work with it?

Comment: You could try [```const_cast```](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) the object.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that the expression `dynamicArray[4]` evaluates without regard to its context: it doesn't know if it's on the left of an assignment or used as a value.  Since `dynamicArray` is not `const`, the non-const (Setter) method gets called.

If you really need to detect the difference, you can use a proxy object (which has some drawbacks of its own):

```
class DynArray {
public:
    class ElemProxy {
    private:
        ElemProxy( DynArray& arr, int pos ) : m_arr(arr), m_pos(pos) {}
        DynArray& m_arr;
        int m_pos;
        friend class DynArray;
    public:
        operator ElType() const { return static_cast<const DynArray&>(m_arr)[m_pos]; }
        ElemProxy& operator=( ElType val ); // Do Setter logic.
    };

    ElemProxy operator[]( int pos ) { return ElemProxy(*this, pos); }
    ElType operator[]( int pos ) const; // Getter
    // ...
};
```